# Запуск программы на 2 каталога выше

Tags: python

Нужно, чтобы программа запускала батник, который лежит на 2 каталога выше.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
os.system("start ../../comand.bat")
```

Но пишет: ".." не является внутреней функцией.

Comment: Укажите абсолютный путь.

Comment: Абсолютный путь постоянно меняется. То есть хочется в независимости от того где находится папка программа запускалась на 2 каталога выше

Comment: а если так:

    os.chdir('../../')

    os.system("start comand.bat")

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощение за беспокойство сам нашел ответ. Вспомнил навыки linux

```
os.system("cd ../.. & start comand.bat")
```

Comment: в этом случае у вас будет другой "текущий каталог", что может влиять на работу запускаемого. альтернативный способ - `os.path.abspath('../../comand.bat')`